# Is it possible to disable CRAM-MD5 authentication for the postfix smtpd server?

Tags: postfix

I'm getting this error in my log

```
warning: SASL authentication failure: no secret in database
```

because the client is trying to use MD5 authentication, and the server needs a database of md5 encrypted passwords.  Clients that just use PLAIN authentication work fine.  (it's only enabled over SSL, so I'm fine with this).   How can I disable MD5 authentication?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but I figured out how to disable that crap.  in `/usr/lib/sasl2/` there's a bunch of library files related to different authentication mechanisms.  They're called things like `libdigestmd5.so`.   If you get rid of the files related to the mechanism you don't want (just put them in some other directory), postfix will not offer those mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do it is to use the configuration files.

if you are using Cyrus SASL then configure your smtpd.conf to use only the mechanisms you want.

```
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```

If you are using dovecot you do that in your dovecot.conf file.

```
auth default {
       mechanisms = plain login
       ...
       ....
}
```

Comment: huh.  I tried mech_list and it just seemed to ignore it.